# wierd chars in command output after RHEL upgrade to 7.3

Tags: rm, locale, putty

I am using SuperPutty on Windows 10 to connect to the recently Upgraded RHEL server (from 6.X to 7.3 Maipo). One of my friends is getting strange `â` character in the output of the `rm` command after upgrade.

```
$ alias rm
rm='rm -i'
$ touch dummy_file.txt
$ rm dummy_file.txt
rm: remove regular empty file âdummy_file.txtâ?
```

Locale information:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I don't know what could be causing this and my user doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Encoding/locale problems? It's probably trying to show pretty quotes `“…”`. Add the output of `locale`, please.

Comment: $ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
Above is the output. Could you please advise, What do I need to do further to fix the issue?

Comment: Is that the output of `locale` run by the user that has this issue or is it from your account? We need to see the output of the command run by the user having the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry terdon, it was output from my account. User is not here right now, I will update the outcome in couple of hours once he comes online. Thanks.

Comment: @ muru and @terdon locale outcome is same for both of us. :(

Comment: In that case, maybe check Putty's settings. Maybe it's set to use a different encoding.

Comment: @muru, yes, that was the issue indeed, thanks and upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we just found the solution. The issue was with Putty configuration.
`"SuperPutty -> Tools -> Putty Configuration -> Windows ->Translation -> Remote Char set"` was set to  `ISO` instead of `UTF8`. 
After we changed the Remote Char set to UTF8, issue is fixed.
[image]
Thanks muru and terdon for your inputs, it helped us in search in right direction.